# Boundary of 2D points

Tags: c++, matlab, 3d

Finding the boundary of points can be useful in many fields of computer science. Currently I have visible vertices of a 3D mesh which I projected 2D. The 2D points will be used to obtain the boundary and various types of edges.

An example image obtained from a matlab link [on a function obtaining the boundary of points](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/boundary.html) shows boundaries (orange and red) of a set of 2D points. The orange boundary uses a shrink factor and is similar to a boundary created by a [convex hull function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convhull.html). In our case we want a more natural boundary of points like the red boundary line (not the one achieved by the convex hull function). The boundary function by matlab is undefined since I am using an older 2014 versions (I assume this is the reason).

Is there another technique/function to achieve the natural boundary line of 2D points? I have tested the convex hull function on the image and it misses a lot of boundary points.

[image: Boundary of Points]`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a more natural boundary? The matlab function uses a shrink factor - are you just wanting to do this with a different shrink or do you have a different set of criteria?

Comment: To add to that: for me it is unclear for the red line why some points are not included, and others are.

Comment: Just to clarify what I meant by natural boundary in terms of the shape of an object. Lets take a car for example. Say it is represented originally by a point cloud in 3D space. I project the point cloud into 2D space from the direction of the camera points. Visually outer 2D points represent the boundary or edge of the car. The contour or edge will curve , sometimes using the convex hull may not represent the contour line of the car realistically. I cant seem to use the boundary function in matlab as it states undefined. On the other hand i tried out the convex hull

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like matlabs boundary function is simply returning the boundary of your pointsets alpha shape: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape

There is an implementation for c++ in cgal: http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Alpha_shapes_2/index.html from that documentation we have:

> [image]
>
> As mentioned in Edelsbrunner's and Mücke's paper [2], one can intuitively think of an α-shape as the following. Imagine a huge mass of ice-cream making up the space ℝ3 and containing the points as "hard" chocolate pieces. Using one of these sphere-formed ice-cream spoons we carve out all parts of the ice-cream block we can reach without bumping into chocolate pieces, thereby even carving out holes in the inside (e.g. parts not reachable by simply moving the spoon from the outside). We will eventually end up with a (not necessarily convex) object bounded by caps, arcs and points. If we now straighten all "round" faces to triangles and line segments, we have an intuitive description of what is called the α-shape of S. Here's an example for this process in 2D (where our ice-cream spoon is simply a circle):

Comment: This is really helpful. So I need the alpha shape. Since I can not use the boundary function to achieve this in matlab. Is there any other way in matlab to obtain the alpha shape.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28851-alpha-shapes    http://www.mathworks.com/examples/matlab/mw/matlab-ex67295599-alpha-shapes       I will test it out to determine if it is what I am looking for.

Comment: @Sade alphashape and its friends where intruduced in 2014b, but there's (not tested by me) this version on matlab central: https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28851-alpha-shapes